# Iterate through ID's in loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, array

I have created a custom loop based on category, now I would like to run a function with the specific ID of the current post being iterated through as a parameter. I have..

```
$secondary_loop = new WP_Query(array( 'category_name' => get_the_title(), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ));
    while ( $secondary_loop->have_posts() ) : $secondary_loop->the_post();
        $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $secondary_loop->posts, 'ID' );
        $current_id = array_pop($post_ids);
        rating($current_id);
        the_title();


       the_content();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

However, with the code above only the 1st array element of `$post_ids` is used. How can I pass the current ID to `rating()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the current post ID within the loop via [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

```
while ( $secondary_loop->have_posts() ) : $secondary_loop->the_post();
    rating( get_the_ID() );
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I noticed I could take `$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $secondary_loop->posts, 'ID' );` out of the loop, and it worked. However, your solution is much less verbose.